# Understanding why LatLng returned from L.GeometryUtil.closest() are not from array being checked over?

Tags: leaflet, geometry

I am using this function below from this library Leaflet.GeometryUtil to help find the closest distance between two points.

```
    L.GeometryUtil,closest(map, array, latlng)
```

It is returning this object below, I can't find this lat and lng in the array I am checking over to see which one is closest to my starting point.

Could someone explain where the lat and lng comes from?

```
    {lat: -85.0511287798, lng: 32.577928810608014, distance: 3049.2708964603326}
```

This is what I have done:

```
var map = L.map("map", { zoomControl: false }).setView(
 [37.8, -96],
 4
);

  
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

const myLocation = {
 lat: 37.0076752995451,
 lon:-120.5956957740688
}

//add starting points 
 L.marker([myLocation.lat, myLocation.lon]).addTo(map)
 
 getAllSpots()
 
 var spotsArray = []
 var allCoords = []

//call function to get all surf spots
 function getAllSpots() {
    fetch("http://api.spitcast.com/api/spot/all", {
      method: "GET"
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        json.map(item => {
          var markers = {
            lon: item.latitude,
            lng: item.longitude,
            spot_name: item.spot_name,
            county_name: item.county_name
          };
          var coords = 
          [ item.longitude,
             item.latitude]
          spotsArray.push(markers);
          allCoords.push(coords);

        });
        
        findDistances(allCoords)
      })
  }
  
    function findDistances(spotsArray) {
            console.log("allCoords",allCoords)
            let closest_latlng = L.GeometryUtil.closest(map, allCoords, [myLocation.lat, myLocation.lon])
console.log(closest_latlng)
L.marker([closest_latlng.lng, closest_latlng.lat]).addTo(map)
  }
  



    var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup();
    
      var markersArray = [];

  
 function addMarkers(json) {
json.forEach(function(feature) {

        markers = mcg.addLayer(
          L.marker([feature.lng, feature.lat], {
            icon: L.icon({
    iconUrl: "map-marker.svg",
    iconSize: [64, 74],
    iconAnchor: [32, 74],
    popupAnchor: [0, -70]
  })
          })
        );

        markersArray.push(mcg);
        return markers;
      })  
     featureGroup = L.featureGroup(markersArray).addTo(map);
  }
```

Comment: Is your array a line\polygon? Are those coordinates on that line/polygon? From the [documentation](http://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#closest) it seems that it simply returns the closest point on the line\polygon, that point might not be a vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you mixed up latitude and longitude when reading from data source http://api.spitcast.com/api/spot/all. If you exchange coordinates, it's OK.

Relevant part of code should look like this:

```
//call function to get all surf spots
function getAllSpots() {
  fetch("http://api.spitcast.com/api/spot/all", {
    method: "GET"
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    json.map(item => {
      var markers = {
        lon: item.longitude,
        lng: item.latitude,
        spot_name: item.spot_name,
        county_name: item.county_name
      };
      var coords = [item.latitude, item.longitude];
      spotsArray.push(markers);
      allCoords.push(coords);

    });       
    findDistances(allCoords)
  })
}

function findDistances(spotsArray) {
  console.log("allCoords", allCoords)
  let closest_latlng = L.GeometryUtil.closest(map, allCoords, [myLocation.lat, myLocation.lon])
  console.log(closest_latlng)
  L.marker([closest_latlng.lat, closest_latlng.lng]).addTo(map)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`L.GeometryUtil.closest` function has 4 parameters:

(map: L.Map, array: Array.<L.LatLng> | Array.<Array.<L.LatLng>> | L.PolyLine | L.Polygon, latlng: L.LatLng, vertices: Boolean).

The last parameter restricts output to a vertex in the given array of coordinates. This is what you are looking for.

More: https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#closest

Example:

```
L.GeometryUtil.closest(myMap,
[
{lat:54.123, lng: 39.123},
{lat:54.354, lng:39.354},
{lat:54.754, lng:39.754}
],
{lat:54.412, lng:39.412},
true)

// {lat: 54.354, lng: 39.354, distance: 1342.6004617904762}
```